# Linux, wierd issues with camera on Debian system

Tags: linux, camera, debian, usb-camera

So, I made some high speed opencv camera detection code, got it running on my debian labtop, and bought some 720p60 chinese usb cam. All worked well. However I wanted to make it run on my TinkerBoard S (tinkerOS - debian).

Here the camera simply refused to get detected, as my lsusb output hinted (also tried guvcview & cheese, none worked):

```
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 05a3:9230 ARC International 
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 1ea7:2001  *this is where i suspect the cam should be*
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 0458:003a KYE Systems Corp. (Mouse Systems) NetScroll+ Mini Traveler / Genius NetScroll 120
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 05e3:0610 Genesys Logic, Inc. 4-port hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 0bda:481a Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

However I think I found the issue, just dont know the solution. When running dmesg, I found the following entries:

```
[   94.277615] usb 1-1.4: new high-speed USB device number 6 using dwc2
[   94.450592] usb 1-1.4: New USB device found, idVendor=05a3, idProduct=9230
[   94.450611] usb 1-1.4: New USB device strings: Mfr=2, Product=1, 
SerialNumber=0
[   94.450625] usb 1-1.4: Product: USB 2.0 Camera
[   94.450637] usb 1-1.4: Manufacturer: HD Camera Manufacturer
[   94.454526] uvcvideo: Found UVC 1.00 device USB 2.0 Camera (05a3:9230)
[   94.496335] uvcvideo: auto-suspend is blacklisted for this device
```

EDIT: both outputs are from the tinker Board.

Comment: Which system are these code blocks from, the laptop or the tinker?

Comment: Tinker, everything works fine on the laptop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like whatever driver is installed on your laptop doesn't exisit on the TinkerOS board.  Going by the second code block, this line looks like the camera:

```
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 05a3:9230 ARC International
```

It would be useful to have a comparison from the laptop to see what's different.

Maybe try [these answers](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/41817/linux-how-to-find-the-device-driver-used-for-a-device) to obtain the driver (on the laptop with the webcam connected).  Be sure to use the same physical ports when changing stuff over, to avoid numbers changing and causing confusion.

Searching the vendor / product code (`05a3:9230`) on google brings up some related results aswell although nothing I found to be conclusive.

Comment: But it's detected on the dmesg output,, I repeat, both are from the Tinker

Answer (score 0):

Dead thread but still feel I should provide the solution.

Turns out that despite the cam being the only one connected, it was somewhere all the way at /dev/video4

whatever be the reason...